# Include custom node id when POST'ing data through the REST API

Tags: nodes, 8

Is it possible to include a custom node id when POST'ing a node using the REST API? Knowing the node id in advance makes it easier to update the nodes in a future stage.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default REST services don't allow that. You could implement yor own. It would need logic that prevents that existing nodes are overwritten exactly.